# browser.get(URL) does not work

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am having an issue with entering text into the address bar nothing happens and I get the error

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the
>   profile. Profile Dir:
>   /var/folders/8_/f48lnzrs7r59_h2yb3dkfbh40000gn/T/tmpsGffLD If you
>   specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for
>   details.

I am able to open the browser but when I uncomment the code `browser.get('http://www.google.com')` nothing happens and I get the error listed above. I am using Firefox 48, Python 2.7.10 and selenium-2.53.6-py2.7.egg

```python
from selenium import webdriver 
browser = webdriver.Firefox() 
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: `Can't load the profile.`  Whatever that means.  Did you specify a `log_file` in the `FirefoxBinary` constructor?  if so, have you checked it for details?  If you haven't specified a log_file, specify one, run it again, and check the log_file.

Answer (score 0):

Change that line to

```
browser.url('http://www.google.com')
```

**OR**

```
browser.open('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: The problem that I am still having is that nothing is being put into the address bar using either browser.url, browser.open or browser.get